# How can I remove the space at the bottom of Bootstrap navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 navigation. When in mobile mode there is extra white space at the bottom of my ul (when the toggle button is clicked and the menu opens, there is white space at the bottom.)

I am bringing in the frame-work through Bootstrap 3 CDN.

HTML

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a>        
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button> 
</div>
... etc
```

Comment: If this is something that's not there on the normal Bootstrap menu, a screenshot would help illustrate the problem better.

Comment: Add a jsFiddle so we can immediately see the problem.

Comment: I haven't been able to bring in bootstrap to jsFiddle. I'm not sure what parameters are all affected in the bootstrap CDN that affects the mobile  drop down

Comment: try bootply.com to add your code. it already has bootstrap